# Apache container cant access php files mounted in /var/www/ - 403 error

Tags: docker, linux, php, apache-httpd

I want to run my php website in a container with apache and php7 
I am using this docker image : https://hub.docker.com/r/nimmis/apache-php7/

I run Fedora so I enter the example command given in docker hub in my terminal.

```
docker run -d -p 8080:80 -v {my_php_app_path}:/var/www/html nimmis/apache-php7
```

The container pull and run fine. But once i try to access the asset (on localhost:8080) I mounted to it, I receive a 403 error. So now i try to connect to the container to see what happens.

I use the command adviced by the author:

```
docker exec -ti <container id> /bin/bash
```

Once in it, I cd to /var/www/html all the file are presents but I cant read or ls in the folder. the root of the container cant do anythig with it. Here is what I get :

```
>>> root@a1f13dc4c29d:/var/www/html# ls
>>> ls: cannot open directory '.': Permission denied
```

Why is it that way ? Am I missing a step ?

Any help would be loved :D

Answer (score 1):

SELinux prevent the docker filesystem to work in the intended way, to fix this issue just add the :Z flag at the end of the volume declaration. It goes something like this:

```
docker run -d -p 8080:80 -v {my_php_app_path}:/var/www/html:Z nimmis/apache-php7
```